# Click button to switch to other tab in actionbar in Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am using Action Bar by set code as bellow:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

I want to use a button in First Tab, when click, change to Second Tab by using:

```
setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
```

Tab change but tab indicator still select on First Tab.

Please Help, Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
//it will switch the tab

viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
//it will set the indicator
```